# Принцип работы удалённого репозитория и команды "git fetch"

Tags: git, fetch, git-pull, git-remote

Если в клонированном репозитории удалить файл локально, то **`git fetch`** не восстанавливает удалённый файл. Для восстановления есть команда `checkout`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что **`git fetch`** не выкачивает потерянную информацию потому, что в удалённом репозитории сохраняется информация о том, что файл был передан ранее, но информации о его утере нет? Хочется полного понимания данного вопроса

Comment: Что вы здесь подразумеваете под "удалить локально"? Удалить на диске или удалить на диске + закоммитить удаление в локальный репозиторий?

Comment: Удаление файла или директории командой **`git rm`** без коммита

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` это `git fetch` + `git merge`.

`git fetch` обновляет локальные данные данными с репозитория (`fetch` и есть собственно команда для обновления), но локальный указатель остается на том же месте, где был до этого.

Т.е. да, ваше понимание в целом верное. В удаленной базе нет информации об удалении файла и по сути, если с момента последнего пула/фетча не было коммитов в базу, то и в процессе `git fetch` ничего не происходит. `git status` покажет вам, что

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    file.txt
```

Т.е. ваша локальная база синхронизирована с удаленной и есть одно изменение без коммита.

Если же в удаленной базе были изменения, то после `git fetch` будет примерно такое:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    file.txt
```

А `git checkout` вообще из немного другой области.

Answer (score 1):

Вы понимаете неправильно.
Следует усвоить термины

- локальное хранилище (содержимое папки .git, где хранятся все изменения на всех ветках),
- удаленное хранилище - аналогично, только на другой машине
- рабочая копия - файлы исходников, с которыми вы работаете - то, что лежит на одном уровне с папкой `.git` и ниже

  `git fetch` только вытягивает базу данных с удаленного хранилища, никаких действий рабочей копией он не делает.

Comment: В моём понимании, Ваш ответ нисколько не противоречит тому, о чём говорил я, за исключением терминов. Если перефразировать мой вопрос, ближе к вашим терминам, то я говорю, что **`git fetch`** выкачивает _базу данных_ и сохраняет информацию о том, что было получено. Удаляя файл из локального, никакой информации об этом до её прямой отправки через **`git push`** не сервер не поступает и именно поэтому повторное выполнение **`git fetch`** не будет работать с утерянными файлами.

Comment: @ЛеонидЕлкин Да, так и есть.